# C# Сортировка перечисления по периоду дат

Tags: c#

Есть свойство типа IEnumerable в которое возвращает коллекцию типа Tuple. Пример:

```
public IEnumerable Items {
        get { return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>[] {
            new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
            new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)),
            new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), DateTime.Now.AddDays(3))
        }; }
    }
```

Собственно вопрос в том как получить коллекцию отсортированную по диапазону дат, т.е. элементы идут последовательно в случае если дата конца периода меньше даты начала периода следующего элемента. Пример:
сейчас

```
{12.08.2018-13.08.2018},{13.08.2018-14.08.2018},{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}
```

требуется

```
{12.08.2018-13.08.2018},{14.08.2018-15.08.2018},{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}
```

если рассмотреть перечисление как карту временных линий:

```
--{12.08.2018-13.08.2018}--------------------------
--------------{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}--------------
--------------------------{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}--
```

сразу видно что периоды пересекаются с другими периодами, а требуется

```
--{12.08.2018-13.08.2018}--------------------------
--------------------------{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}--
--------------{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}--------------
```

либо представить уже в двух временных линиях

```
--{12.08.2018-13.08.2018}-{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}--
--------------{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}--------------
```

Comment: по какому принципу вы хотите сортировать?

Comment: просто из последовательности получить другую последовательность, можно и без сохранения оригинальной последовательности

Comment: у вас вопрос о сортировке. Я и спрашиваю, какой принцип сортировки, что вам нужна?

Comment: хорошо, опишу еще раз. Есть перечисление объектов в котором есть два свойства типа DateTime: начало периода и конец периода. Требуется отсортировать элементы таким образом что бы их периоды шли максимально последовательно.

Comment: Какой критерий последовательности? Я этого не понимаю. С моей точки зрения то, что у вас под текстом `требуется` - сортировано не последовательно.

Comment: если сортировку рассматривать с точки зрения одного значения, то да, последовательность выглядит не последовательной. Требуется составить последовательность элементов таким образом что бы все элементы выстраивали цепочки из диапазонов.

Comment: {12,13}-{14, 15}-{13-14} - по какому принципу это объединено? Тут нет цепочек, тут первый элемент, потом третий. потом второй.

Comment: если рассмотреть перечисление как карту временных линий:

--{12.08.2018-13.08.2018}--------------------------
--------------{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}--------------
--------------------------{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}--


сразу видно что периоды пересекаются с другими периодами

--{12.08.2018-13.08.2018}--------------------------
--------------------------{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}--
--------------{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}--------------

либо представить уже в двух временных линиях

--{12.08.2018-13.08.2018}-{14.08.2018-15.08.2018}--
--------------{13.08.2018-14.08.2018}--------------

Comment: я извиняюсь, может это со мной чтото не так, но я не могу понять принцип, по которому вы хотите сортировать интервалы времени. В любом случае, будет полезным внести ваши уточнения (вообще максимально расписать что вы хотите в этой сортировке) в ваш вопрос - может, кто то другой будет мимо проходить и поймет вас и ответит

Comment: благодарю, уже вес изменения

Comment: как бы вы отсортировали {12-15}, {13-16}, {14-17}? Что значит две временные линии? Два коллекции на выходе?

Comment: Верно ли то, что вам надо на выходе иметь минимальный набор коллекций, каждая из которых содержит непересекающиеся интервалы?

Comment: увы, но нет. На выходе должна быть одна коллекция. Представленную вами коллекцию оставил бы такой же. Карта веменных линий:

 --{12-15}------
 ----{13-16}----
 ------{14-17}--

если диапазон для паследнего изменить на {16-17}:
то тогда можно получить цепучку диапазонов:
 --{12-15}{16-17}-
 ----{13-16}----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую поделить интервалы так, чтобы рядом не находилось минимум пересекающихся. Не претендую на оптимальность по времени\памяти, не заморачивался с этим. 
Код сортировки:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> Sort(IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> intervals)
{
    var sortedByStart = intervals.OrderBy(x => x.Item1);
    var result = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
    var awaitingStack = new Stack<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();

    foreach (var i in sortedByStart)
    {
        if (result.Count == 0)
        {
            result.Add(i);
            continue;
        }

        if (awaitingStack.Count > 0)
        {
            while (!Intersects(awaitingStack.Peek(), result.Last()))
            {
                result.Add(awaitingStack.Pop());
            }
        }

        if (Intersects(i, result.Last()))
            awaitingStack.Push(i);
        else result.Add(i);
    }

    if (awaitingStack.Count > 0)
        result.AddRange(Sort(awaitingStack));
    return result;
}

private bool Intersects(Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> i1, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> i2)
{
    if (i1.Item1 > i2.Item2) return false;
    if (i1.Item2 < i2.Item1) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Примеры использования

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var intervals = new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>[] {
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today, today.AddDays(1)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today.AddDays(1), today.AddDays(2)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today.AddDays(2), today.AddDays(3))};

foreach (var i in Sort(intervals)) Console.WriteLine($"{{{i.Item1} - {i.Item2}}}");

Console.WriteLine("--------------");

intervals = new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>[] {
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today, today.AddDays(3)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today.AddDays(1), today.AddDays(4)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today.AddDays(2), today.AddDays(5))};

foreach (var i in Sort(intervals)) Console.WriteLine($"{{{i.Item1} - {i.Item2}}}");

Console.WriteLine("--------------");

intervals = new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>[] {
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today, today.AddDays(3)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today.AddDays(1), today.AddDays(4)),
        new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(today.AddDays(4), today.AddDays(5))};

foreach (var i in Sort(intervals)) Console.WriteLine($"{{{i.Item1} - {i.Item2}}}");
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
{12.08.2018 0:00:00 - 13.08.2018 0:00:00}
{14.08.2018 0:00:00 - 15.08.2018 0:00:00}
{13.08.2018 0:00:00 - 14.08.2018 0:00:00}
--------------
{12.08.2018 0:00:00 - 15.08.2018 0:00:00}
{13.08.2018 0:00:00 - 16.08.2018 0:00:00}
{14.08.2018 0:00:00 - 17.08.2018 0:00:00}
--------------
{12.08.2018 0:00:00 - 15.08.2018 0:00:00}
{16.08.2018 0:00:00 - 17.08.2018 0:00:00}
{13.08.2018 0:00:00 - 16.08.2018 0:00:00}
```

Comment: спасибо. Отмечаю как ответ

Comment: @TomDugger отмечайте только если помогло решить проблему

Comment: помогло, Еше раз спасибо